# machine learning for a small longitudinal or panel data set

Tags: machine-learning, r, regression

I would appreciate if you could let me know what machine learning techniques are suitable for a small longitudinal data set with time varying covariates. Some part of data set:

```
ID  TIME        Y         x1      x2      x3      x4      x5
1   1        0 .060     1.28    0.02    0.87    1.22    0.06
1   2        0.110      1.27    0.01    0.82    1.00    -0.01
1   3        -0.456     1.05    -0.06   0.92    0.73    0.02
1   4        -0.325     1.11    -0.02   0.86    0.81    0.08
1   5        -0.567     1.22    -0.06   0.89    0.48    0.01
2   1        1.251      1.06    0.11    0.81    0.84    0.20
2   2        1.357      1.06    0.08    0.88    0.69    0.14
2   3        0.007      0.97    0.08    0.91    0.81    0.17
2   4        1.20       1.06    0.13    0.82    0.88    0.23
2   5        2.235      1.12    0.15    0.76    1.08    0.28
2   6        1.340      1.60    0.26    0.55    1.31    0.37
2   7        2.470      1.58    0.26    0.56    1.16    0.35
2   8        2.346      1.54    0.24    0.59    1.08    0.33
2   9        2.250      1.72    0.22    0.55    0.84    0.29
2   10       2.283      1.72    0.21    0.53    0.79    0.29
2   11       1.798      1.63    0.19    0.55    0.73    0.27
2   12       2.828      2.17    0.32    0.44    0.95    0.43
3   1        -0.303     0.87    -0.03   0.79    0.61    0.00
3   2        -0.888     0.83    -0.14   0.95    0.57    -0.02
```

It seems that "MixRF" and "mboost" are among those R packages that could deal with panel data sets but unfortunately I couldn't understand how to use them on my data set.
Best regards,

Comment: For `MixRF`, an example is provided in [the manual](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MixRF/versions/1.0/topics/MixRF). Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: @JiebiaoWang Thanks. Unfortunately, I could not manage to load the data set which is used in the example provided in the manual. Therefore, I could not see what to do? I want to use 30% of my data as test set and the remaining 70% as train set.        library(MixRF)
library(lme4)
data(sleepstudy)

Comment: Sorry about that. Please call `library(lme4)` before loading the `sleepstudy` data set. For the training / test sets, you can feed the training set into `MixRF()` and use [`predict.MixRF()`](https://github.com/randel/MixRF/blob/master/R/predict.MixRF.r) for the prediction on the test set.

Comment: @JiebiaoWang Thanks a lot. In fact, I have 123 features so I write: library(readxl)

Comment: `library(lme4) library(MixRF) data=read.csv("my_X-1c.csv",header=TRUE) set.seed(123) train_ind <- sample(1:152, floor(0.70*152), replace=F) train <- data[which(data$id
 %in% c(train_ind)),  test <- data[-which(data$id %in% c(train_ind)), ] tmp = MixRF(Y = train$y,X=as.data.frame(train[,1:123]),random="(time|id)",data=train,initialRandomEffects=0,ErrorTolerance=0.01,MaxIterations=100) tmp$forest tmp$MixedModel 
tmp$RandomEffects predict.MixRF(test[,1:123])`

Comment: However, this error is reported: could not find function "predict.MixRF". I also tried  `predict.tmp(test[,1:123]) ` but again that error is produced.

Comment: Please download it from the link I provided in my last comment and call `source('predict.MixRF.r')` to use it. I will incorporate `predict.MixRF()` into the next version on CRAN.

Comment: @JiebiaoWang Thanks. Unfortunately, If I use this command `pred=predict.MixRF(tmp,test[,1:123])`, this error is reported:  `Error in predict.randomForest(object$forest, x) : object 'x' not found`. However, my data is unbalanced. Besides, I divide my data into test and train in a way that some new subjects are included in test data (i.e., different "ids" except those which are included in the train sample.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will extend `predict.MixRF()` to unbalanced data this week. Will keep you posted.

Comment: @JiebiaoWang Thanks for your time and consideration. Besides, I would appreciate if you could guide me to do [discrete time survival analysis](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1378877-discrete-time-survival-analysis)

Comment: The [`predict.MixRF` function](https://github.com/randel/MixRF/blob/master/R/predict.MixRF.r) should work for unbalanced data now. For the discrete time survival analysis, my understanding is that it can be solved with a mixed-effects logistic regression. Please ask it as a new question, for example, on [Cross Validated (stats)](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JiebiaoWang Thanks. I will try it. I asked it  [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270230/discrete-time-survival-analysis) as a new question.

Comment: @JiebiaoWang Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge and time. I would appreciate if you could let me know whether "MixRF" could provide feature importance as well as how to determine MSE of the test set.

Comment: You can use the feature importance function in `randomForest` on the fitted `tmp$forest`. MSE can be easily calculated by hand using `mean((true - prediction)^2)`.

Comment: @JiebiaoWang. Thanks a lot. My MSE for test set is about 0.85. Could you please let me know if it is possible to tune hyper-parameters in order to find the best parameters with the minimum MSE?

Comment: I incorporated the arguments of `randomForest` into the [GitHub](https://github.com/randel/MixRF/blob/master/R/MixRF.r) version of `MixRF`. You can tune parameters for `MixRF` in the same way as for `randomForest`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56302/discussion-on-question-by-ebrahimi-machine-learning-for-a-small-longitudinal-or).

Comment: @JiebiaoWang Sorry could please let me know how to tune it using rBayesianOptimization package? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry that I do not have any experience with `rBayesianOptimization`. Basically, `MixRF` keeps all arguments of `randomForest`. I expect that as long as you know how to tune `randomForest`, it is the same thing for `MixRF`.

Comment: @JiebiaoWang. Thanks. I know how to tune it in Python. Could you please tune it using any method that you prefer? Best regards.